# Микросервисная архитектура при помощи Docker, Consul, Consul-Template и балансировщика нагрузки

Tags: nginx, docker, docker-compose, микросервисы

Добрый день!

Я новичок в Docker. Разбираюсь со связкой Docker-machine + docker-comppose + consul + consul-template + registator. Нашел [статью](https://tech.bellycard.com/blog/load-balancing-docker-containers-with-nginx-and-consul-template/), в которой есть [пример](https://github.com/bellycard/docker-loadbalancer). Но есть некоторые отличия:

Я использую docker-machine:

```
docker-machine create -d azure --azure-subscription-id <id> \
                               --azure-ssh-user <name> \
                               --azure-open-port 80 \
                               --azure-subnet-prefix 10.0.2.0/24
```

так же использую docker-compose, а не fig:

```
app:
  image: tutum/hello-world:latest
  environment:
    SERVICE_NAME: app
    SERVICE_TAGS: production
    SERVICE_80_NAME: http
    SERVICE_80_CHECK_HTTP: .
    SERVICE_80_CHECK_INTERVAL: 15
  ports:
  - "80"

lb:
  build: ./
  links:
  - consul
  ports:
  - "80:80"

consul:
  command: -server -bootstrap -advertise 10.0.2.4
  image: gliderlabs/consul-server
  ports:
  - "8300:8300"
  - "8400:8400"
  - "8500:8500"
  - "8600:53/udp"
#
# Service Discovery - Registrator
#
registrator:
  command: -ip=10.0.2.4 consul://consul:8500
  image: gliderlabs/registrator:latest
  links:
  - consul
  volumes:
  - "/var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock"
```

Проблема в следующем:
После запуска контейнеров приложение не регистрируется и соответственно, при обращении на 80 порт, nginx возвращает ошибку 502.
вывод консоли при этом:

```
docker-compose up                    
Starting dockerloadbalancer_app_1 ... 
Starting dockerloadbalancer_app_1
Starting dockerloadbalancer_consul_1 ... 
Starting dockerloadbalancer_consul_1 ... done
Starting dockerloadbalancer_lb_1 ... 
Starting dockerloadbalancer_registrator_1 ... 
Starting dockerloadbalancer_lb_1 ... done ... done
Starting dockerloadbalancer_registrator_1
Attaching to dockerloadbalancer_app_1, dockerloadbalancer_consul_1, dockerloadbalancer_registrator_1, dockerloadbalancer_lb_1
consul_1       | ==> WARNING: Bootstrap mode enabled! Do not enable unless necessary
consul_1       | ==> Starting Consul agent...
consul_1       | ==> Starting Consul agent RPC...
registrator_1  | 2017/08/30 05:09:13 Starting registrator v7 ...
registrator_1  | 2017/08/30 05:09:13 Forcing host IP to 10.0.2.4
registrator_1  | 2017/08/30 05:09:13 Using consul adapter: consul://consul:8500
registrator_1  | 2017/08/30 05:09:13 Connecting to backend (0/0)
lb_1           | nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
consul_1       | ==> Consul agent running!
consul_1       |          Node name: '66269e63b117'
consul_1       |         Datacenter: 'dc1'
consul_1       |             Server: true (bootstrap: true)
consul_1       |        Client Addr: 0.0.0.0 (HTTP: 8500, HTTPS: -1, DNS: 8600, RPC: 8400)
consul_1       |       Cluster Addr: 10.0.2.4 (LAN: 8301, WAN: 8302)
consul_1       |     Gossip encrypt: false, RPC-TLS: false, TLS-Incoming: false
consul_1       |              Atlas: <disabled>
consul_1       | 
consul_1       | ==> Log data will now stream in as it occurs:
consul_1       | 
consul_1       |     2017/08/30 05:09:09 [INFO] raft: Node at 10.0.2.4:8300 [Follower] entering Follower state
consul_1       |     2017/08/30 05:09:09 [INFO] serf: EventMemberJoin: 66269e63b117 10.0.2.4
consul_1       |     2017/08/30 05:09:09 [INFO] consul: adding LAN server 66269e63b117 (Addr: 10.0.2.4:8300) (DC: dc1)
consul_1       |     2017/08/30 05:09:09 [INFO] serf: EventMemberJoin: 66269e63b117.dc1 10.0.2.4
consul_1       |     2017/08/30 05:09:09 [INFO] consul: adding WAN server 66269e63b117.dc1 (Addr: 10.0.2.4:8300) (DC: dc1)
consul_1       |     2017/08/30 05:09:09 [ERR] agent: failed to sync remote state: No cluster leader
consul_1       |     2017/08/30 05:09:10 [WARN] raft: Heartbeat timeout reached, starting election
consul_1       |     2017/08/30 05:09:10 [INFO] raft: Node at 10.0.2.4:8300 [Candidate] entering Candidate state
consul_1       |     2017/08/30 05:09:10 [INFO] raft: Election won. Tally: 1
consul_1       |     2017/08/30 05:09:10 [INFO] raft: Node at 10.0.2.4:8300 [Leader] entering Leader state
consul_1       |     2017/08/30 05:09:10 [INFO] consul: cluster leadership acquired
consul_1       |     2017/08/30 05:09:10 [INFO] consul: New leader elected: 66269e63b117
consul_1       |     2017/08/30 05:09:10 [INFO] raft: Disabling EnableSingleNode (bootstrap)
consul_1       |     2017/08/30 05:09:13 [INFO] agent: Synced node info
consul_1       |     2017/08/30 05:09:13 [WARN] Service name "dockerloadbalancer_lb-80" will not be discoverable via DNS due to invalid characters. Valid characters include all alpha-numerics and dashes.
consul_1       |     2017/08/30 05:09:13 [INFO] agent: Synced service '54a66f0e387b:dockerloadbalancer_lb_1:80'
consul_1       |     2017/08/30 05:09:13 [INFO] agent: Synced service '54a66f0e387b:dockerloadbalancer_consul_1:8400'
consul_1       |     2017/08/30 05:09:13 [INFO] agent: Synced service '54a66f0e387b:dockerloadbalancer_consul_1:8500'
consul_1       |     2017/08/30 05:09:13 [INFO] agent: Synced service '54a66f0e387b:dockerloadbalancer_consul_1:53:udp'
registrator_1  | 2017/08/30 05:09:13 consul: current leader  10.0.2.4:8300
registrator_1  | 2017/08/30 05:09:13 Listening for Docker events ...
registrator_1  | 2017/08/30 05:09:13 Syncing services on 4 containers
registrator_1  | 2017/08/30 05:09:13 added: 07b7de523f24 54a66f0e387b:dockerloadbalancer_lb_1:80
registrator_1  | 2017/08/30 05:09:13 ignored: 07b7de523f24 port 443 not published on host
registrator_1  | 2017/08/30 05:09:13 ignored: 54a66f0e387b no published ports
registrator_1  | 2017/08/30 05:09:13 ignored: 66269e63b117 port 8302 not published on host
registrator_1  | 2017/08/30 05:09:13 ignored: 66269e63b117 port 8600 not published on host
registrator_1  | 2017/08/30 05:09:13 ignored: 66269e63b117 port 8600 not published on host
registrator_1  | 2017/08/30 05:09:13 ignored: 66269e63b117 port 8301 not published on host
registrator_1  | 2017/08/30 05:09:13 ignored: 66269e63b117 port 8302 not published on host
registrator_1  | 2017/08/30 05:09:13 added: 66269e63b117 54a66f0e387b:dockerloadbalancer_consul_1:8400
registrator_1  | 2017/08/30 05:09:13 added: 66269e63b117 54a66f0e387b:dockerloadbalancer_consul_1:8500
registrator_1  | 2017/08/30 05:09:13 added: 66269e63b117 54a66f0e387b:dockerloadbalancer_consul_1:53:udp
registrator_1  | 2017/08/30 05:09:13 added: 66269e63b117 54a66f0e387b:dockerloadbalancer_consul_1:8300
registrator_1  | 2017/08/30 05:09:13 ignored: 66269e63b117 port 8301 not published on host
registrator_1  | 2017/08/30 05:09:13 register failed: &{54a66f0e387b:dockerloadbalancer_app_1:80 http 32780 10.0.2.4 [production] map[check_http:. check_interval:15] 0 {32780 10.0.2.4 80 172.17.0.2 tcp 819676e02aa1 819676e02aa10e14b1eca7e80d934f77932e66001bb24f237c5cde7035fcf509  0xc2080f4a80}} Unexpected response code: 400 (Request decode failed: time: missing unit in duration 15)
consul_1       |     2017/08/30 05:09:13 [INFO] agent: Synced service '54a66f0e387b:dockerloadbalancer_consul_1:8300'
lb_1           | nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
lb_1           | 2017/08/30 05:09:44 [error] 14#0: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 217.118.84.156, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:65535/", host: "13.64.158.172"
lb_1           | 217.118.84.156 - - [30/Aug/2017:05:09:44 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 502 575 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.101 Safari/537.36" "-"
lb_1           | 2017/08/30 05:09:45 [error] 14#0: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 217.118.84.156, server: , request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:65535/favicon.ico", host: "13.64.158.172", referrer: "http://13.64.158.172/"
```

Подскажите в чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ошибка в статье, в файл nginx.conf, должен выглядеть так:

```
upstream app {
  least_conn;
  {{range service "production.http"}}
  server {{.Address}}:{{.Port}} max_fails=3 fail_timeout=60 weight=1;
  {{else}}
  server 127.0.0.1:65333; # force a 501
  {{end}}  
}

server {
  listen 80 default_server;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://app;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
  }
}

server {
  listen 65333;

  location / {
    types {
      application/json json;
    }
    default_type "application/json";
    return 501 '{
  "success": false,
  "deploy": false,
  "status": 501,
  "body": {
    "message": "No available upstream servers at current route from consul"
  }
}';
  }
}
```

Полностью рабочий пример выложил [сюда](https://github.com/RogerW/docker-loadbalancer.git)